# Use webpack to bundle all node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I am using Webpack to bundle a node project. In the project I am using `conventional-recommended-bump` to bump the package version. 
When I run webpack I get the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/conventional-changelog-preset-loader/index.js 5:30-37
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./node_modules/conventional-recommended-bump/index.js
```

Then when I run the bundle I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to load the "angular" preset package. Please make sure it's installed.
```

This suggests to me that webpack has failed to bundle all the dependencies included in the package I am using.

My webpack config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            handlebars: 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js',
        },
        modules: ['node_modules'],
    },
    target: 'node',

};
```

Nothing obvious to me why webpack is failing to include the releveant dependencies in the bundle.

I tried adding this to the config, it got rid of the warning but the output was still the same.

```
  module: {
        unknownContextCritical: false,
    },
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: could you share more details how your package.json looks like, are you trying to include devDependencies like conventional-recommended-bump in your bundle ?

Comment: Its under the dependencies section. 
`
  "dependencies": {
    "conventional-recommended-bump": "^6.0.5",
    "execa": "^4.0.2",
    "find-up": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.2",
    "standard-version": "^8.0.0"
  }`

Comment: Please consider moving conventional-recommended-bump, standard-version, prettier, pretty-quick, semver packages to devDependencies, as they are not for runtime usage.

Comment: For the package I am building, they are for runtime usage. Not sure anything will change if I move them to devDependencies?